# Unable to link VSTS and SonarQube - JAVA_HOME not found in your environment

Tags: sonarqube, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I would appreciate any assistance on the following issue I'm experiencing.

I have 3 servers, a private build server, a SonarQube web/app server and a SonarQube db server.

SonarQube is working all fine, I can successfully run SonarQube via command line to populate the SonarQube DB with my project code quality from the build server.

The issue I'm facing is when I use the SonarQube build steps in VSTS (Visual Studio Team Services) and try to automate the steps.

I receive the following error during the step 'Finish the analysis and upload the results to SonarQube:

**ERROR: JAVA_HOME not found in your environment, and no Java executable present in the PATH.
Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the location of your Java installation, or add "java.exe" to the PATH**

In my capabilities (within VSTS) for the build agent, I've added the following user capability:

PATH         - %JAVA_HOME%\bin
JAVA_HOME    - C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_101

Java is definitely installed on the build server and working as I can run the SonarQube build via command line.  Not sure why VSTS can't see JAVA_HOME.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry, the formatting seems to have been lost and the user capabilities may not be clear above.  I've added 'PATH - %JAVA_HOME%\bin' and then another capability for 'JAVA_HOME - C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_101'

Comment: Do you mean your issue has been solved? If so, you can post a new answer and mark it as answer after 24 hours.

Comment: No sorry, I meant the formatting in my stack overflow question seemed to lost the line breaks when I posted the question so it joined the two user capabilities together which may have looked confusing.  So I just wanted to clarify that I've added 2 separate user capabilities as in my comment above.  This issue is still outstanding.

Comment: your issue has been solved, you can mark it answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The build service/agent only get the capability when it starts. So you need to restart the build service/agent to refresh the capability after your system environment is changed such as environment variable changed, new software installed. When you reboot the build server, the build service/agent is restarted, that's why it works.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I can't explain why this is working today.  The only thing is that I switched off the build server last night and switched it on this morning, so maybe a restart was required?  Can't see why.

Sorry I can't provide more info why it is working now!

Comment: The build agent capability will be updated after restart build server. You can restart build agent first, if it doesn't work, you can restart build server. Your issue has been solved, you can mark it after 24 hours.